# What is wrong with this code? Binary to Decimal Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a binary to decimal converter in batch to work with CMD. I am having an issue where some binary numbers give me a higher decimal number than it is supposed to. What confuses me though is that 11111111 gives me 255.
Here are some examples of wrong numbers given.
01110101 gave the number 297.
01111010 gave the number 312.
01111101 gave the number 321.

```
@Echo off
Color 0e

:Start
Title Binary to Decimal
Set /p Bin=Binary Number?
Set Dec=0

:Check
If %Bin% GEQ 10000000 Goto ADD128
If %Bin% GEQ 1000000 Goto ADD64
If %Bin% GEQ 100000 Goto ADD32
If %Bin% GEQ 10000 Goto ADD16
If %Bin% GEQ 1000 Goto ADD8
If %Bin% GEQ 100 Goto ADD4
If %Bin% GEQ 10 Goto ADD2
If %Bin% GEQ 1 Goto ADD1
Goto Fin

:ADD128
Set /a Dec= %Dec% + 128
Set /a Bin= %Bin% - 10000000
Goto Check

:ADD64
Set /a Dec= %Dec% + 64
Set /a Bin= %Bin% - 1000000
Goto Check

:ADD32
Set /a Dec= %Dec% + 32
Set /a Bin= %Bin% - 100000
Goto Check

:ADD16
Set /a Dec= %Dec% + 16
Set /a Bin= %Bin% - 10000
Goto Check

:ADD8
Set /a Dec= %Dec% + 8
Set /a Bin= %Bin% - 1000
Goto Check

:ADD4
Set /a Dec= %Dec% + 4
Set /a Bin= %Bin% - 100
Goto Check

:ADD2
Set /a Dec= %Dec% + 2
Set /a Bin= %Bin% - 10
Goto Check

:ADD1
Set /a Dec= %Dec% + 1
Set /a Bin= %Bin% - 1
Goto Check

:Fin
Echo %Dec%
Pause
Goto Start
```

Comment: Edit your post to add some examples of incorrect conversions - don't leave us to guess.

Answer (score 3):

That's fun, it's not what I expected.

Edit your code so that each of the add calls shows you what it's doing, e.g.:

```
:ADD128
echo (Bin: %Bin%) (Dec: %Dec%) Adding 128
Set /a Dec= %Dec% + 128
Set /a Bin= %Bin% - 10000000
Goto Check
```

`01111010` does this:

```
Binary Number?01111010
(Bin: 01111010) (Dec: 0) Adding 32
(Bin: 199528) (Dec: 32) Adding 32
(Bin: 99528) (Dec: 64) Adding 16
(Bin: 89528) (Dec: 80) Adding 16
(Bin: 79528) (Dec: 96) Adding 16
(Bin: 69528) (Dec: 112) Adding 16
(Bin: 59528) (Dec: 128) Adding 16
(Bin: 49528) (Dec: 144) Adding 16
(Bin: 39528) (Dec: 160) Adding 16
(Bin: 29528) (Dec: 176) Adding 16
(Bin: 19528) (Dec: 192) Adding 16
(Bin: 9528) (Dec: 208) Adding 8
(Bin: 8528) (Dec: 216) Adding 8
(Bin: 7528) (Dec: 224) Adding 8
(Bin: 6528) (Dec: 232) Adding 8
(Bin: 5528) (Dec: 240) Adding 8
(Bin: 4528) (Dec: 248) Adding 8
(Bin: 3528) (Dec: 256) Adding 8
(Bin: 2528) (Dec: 264) Adding 8
(Bin: 1528) (Dec: 272) Adding 8
(Bin: 528) (Dec: 280) Adding 4
(Bin: 428) (Dec: 284) Adding 4
(Bin: 328) (Dec: 288) Adding 4
(Bin: 228) (Dec: 292) Adding 4
(Bin: 128) (Dec: 296) Adding 4
(Bin: 28) (Dec: 300) Adding 2
(Bin: 18) (Dec: 302) Adding 2
(Bin: 8) (Dec: 304) Adding 1
(Bin: 7) (Dec: 305) Adding 1
(Bin: 6) (Dec: 306) Adding 1
(Bin: 5) (Dec: 307) Adding 1
(Bin: 4) (Dec: 308) Adding 1
(Bin: 3) (Dec: 309) Adding 1
(Bin: 2) (Dec: 310) Adding 1
(Bin: 1) (Dec: 311) Adding 1
312
```

Because it starts with a 0, the command prompt `if` and `set` are interpreting it as *octal* - base 8.

Since your algorithm isn't actually working with binary numbers, it's working with base ten numbers and relies on convenient similarity of base 10 powers of ten and base 2 powers of two, interpreting some things as octal ruins it.

Any number that starts with 0 will (probably) be wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much I didn't know leading 0s made it an octal.

Comment: +1, because this exactly answers the question ("What is wrong with this code?") without any hint, how to solve it ;)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not what you asked for, but this is the way I would do such conversion (up to 31 binary digits).

**EDIT**: I slightly modified the code so it can now convert a 32-bits signed number.

```
@Echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Color 0e
Title Binary to Decimal

:Start
Set /p Bin=Binary Number?
Set Dec=0
for /L %%i in (1,1,32) do if defined Bin (
   set /A "Dec=(Dec<<1)|!Bin:~0,1!"
   set "Bin=!Bin:~1!"
)
Echo %Dec%
Pause
Goto Start
```

Perhaps you may be interested in [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4022&p=22370#p22370).

Comment: Interesting... I tried with the `<<` operator but without success. It seems to need the quotes. On the other hand, my german `set /?` claims, there is a prefix `0b` for binary values (which doesn't work), so I didn't invest much time for investigation.

Answer (score 1):

with a little bit of logic and math, you can shorten your code dramatically:

```
@Echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Color 0e

:Start
Title Binary to Decimal
Set /p Bin=Binary Number?
Set Dec=0
set pot=1

:Check
for /L %%i in (7,-1,0) do (
  if "!Bin:~%%i,1!" == "1" set /a dec +=!pot!
  REM echo Stelle:%%i   Potenz:!pot!    Binary:!Bin:~%%i,1! Decimal:!dec!
  set /a pot*=2
)

:Fin
Echo %bin% = %Dec%
Pause
Goto Start
```

The trick: look at the single numbers from right to left and if it is `1`, add the according potence to two.

Comment: I figured out how to remove the leading 0's and shortened my original code to 14 lines. This is a nice example of how to do it though thanks.